# Angular directive template unknown scope

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I know there is a lot of questions and posts about AngularJS and how directives are supposed to be used. And I got mine working just fine until I got another problem which I don't know how to resolve.

I use a directive on a custom HTML element. Directive transforms this element into a regular html tree as defined in a template. The HTML element has some attributes which are used when building the template. Data for one of the elements is received with HTTP request and is successfully loaded. This is the part which I got working fine.

Now I want to do something more. [I've created a plunker which is an example of what I want to achieve.](https://plnkr.co/UFbD5B0wf2kgYsWYpDBX) It's a fake one, but illustrates my problem well.

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="phones">
        <phone brand="SmartBrand" model="xx" comment="blah"></phone>
        <phone brand="SmarterBrand" model="abc" comment="other {{dynamic.c1}}"></phone>
    </div>
</body>
```

Angular directive:

```
app.directive('phone', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            'comment': '@',
            'brand': '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'customTpl.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            fakeResponse = {
                "data": {
                    "success": true,
                    "data": "X300",
                    "dynamic": {
                        "c1": "12",
                        "c2": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
            $scope.model = fakeResponse.data.data;
            $scope.dynamic = fakeResponse.data.dynamic;
        }
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="phone">
    <header>
        <h2>{{brand}} <strong>{{model}}</strong></h2>
    </header>
    <p>Comment: <strong>{{comment}}</strong></p>
</div>
```

So I would like to be able to customize one of the tags in the element (phone comment in this example). The trick is that the number of additional info that is going to be in the tag may vary. The only thing I can be sure of is that the names will match the ones received from AJAX request. I can make the entire comment be received with AJAX and that will solve my problem. But I want to separate template from the variables it is built with. Is it possible?

Comment: you can separate the dynamic part as another directive or as a ngRepeat statement, then you loop, and as much as number of dynamic data you have it will show elements

Comment: @xelilof thanks for your reply. what if the comment for one phone would be like: `comment="I want {{dynamic.c1}} hours of playtime in {{dynamic.c2}} lifetime"` while for other phone it would look like: `comment="It is unclear if {{dynamic.c1}} monkeys can destroy {{dynamic.c2}} phone in {{dynamic.c3}} hour"` ? I guess ng-repeat won't do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working. It may not be the state of the art solution (I think @xelilof suggestion to do it with another directive may be more correct), but I'm out of ideas on how to do it (so feel free to help me out).

I've turned the `{{comment}}` part into a microtemplate which is analysed by a service. [I've made a plunk to show you a working sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/jTqoZEyUBOAxTeziOLFQ).

The JS part looks like this now:

```
app.directive('phone', ['dynamic', function(dynamic) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      'comment': '@',
      'brand': '@',
      'color': '@',
      'photo': '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'customTpl.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      fakeResponse = {
        "data": {
          "success": true,
          "data": "X300",
          "dynamic": {
            "c1": "12",
            "c2": "2"
          }
        }
      }
      $scope.model = fakeResponse.data.data;
      $scope.comment2 = dynamic($scope.comment, fakeResponse.data.dynamic);
      console.log("Comment after 'dynamic' service is: " + $scope.comment);
    }


  }
}]);

app.factory('dynamic', function() {
  return function(template, vars) {
    for (var v in vars) {
      console.log("Parsing variable " + v + " which value is " + vars[v]);
      template = template.replace("::" + v + "::", vars[v]);
    }
    return template;
  }

});
```